# elastic ip for ec2 AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just created an EC2 AMI Linux to host an elasticsearch setup. I see a public ip allocated for the instance but I'm assuming it's not a static ip.

When I go to `Elastic IPS > Allocate New Address`.
It creates one but then I cannot associate it with my EC2 AMI which is running.

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: what error you get when you `I cannot associate it with my EC2 AMI which is running.` There must be some error if it fails to associate an elastic ip to ec2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a static IP for most purposes.

The intent is that you setup a CNAME that points to your AWS host name, which in turn resolves to the assigned IP.  Your DNS never contains AWS IPs, just CNAMES mappings to AWS assigned host names.

To create a CNAME, just go to your DNS provider, login, enter the new CNAME record with your desired name (eg. "www"), then enter the AWS assigned host name as the target.

Comment: Thank you Jeff, interesting alternative. I'm seeing on my instance, Private DNS. Would this be what I enter in the CNAME value on Amazon Route 53 and create a name alias to it?

Comment: It'd be the public dns.

Comment: It's showing '-', is this because it's a VPC? I'm confused about this, it won't let me create an EC2 without VPC now.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by "it's showing '-'".  Whatever the host name that it gives you, you can put that in as a CNAME in your DNS provider's management console.  Just make sure your security policy opens up any ports you want to expose, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ASSOCIATE the IP to the instance.

Comment: At first the problem was that in the list during association, my ec2 instance were not showing up! But I just tried again and now I selected VPC instead of EC2 and they show up! So I should use this instead of Jeff's suggestion?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. If you use CNAME's you will have to update the CNAME every time the ec2 instance name changes (shutdown/new instance/scaling/etc). If you want a static IP then you can just set an A record. Of course you can also throw your whole environment in VPCs and attach a static IP to a nat. All based on use case.